# Word or phrase for "people who fake niceness temporarily to get benefits"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a word or phrase for "people who fake niceness temporarily to get benefits"?

Comment: *Fake* comes to mind, as does *insincere.*

Comment: This is the English Language and Usage site. I suggest you phrase your questions in English if you don’t want people to think you are being rude when you don’t, you know.

Comment: Perhaps *two-faced* or *duplicitous*.

Answer (score 1):

To act on ***self- interest*** , is an expression that may fit in your context.

> - personal advantage or interest.

- he was so nice to me just out of self-interest.

To ***ingraziate*** may suggest a behavior which aims at a personal advantage

> - to establish (oneself) in the favor or good graces of others, esp. by deliberate effort: *to ingratiate oneself with the boss.*

The Free Dictionary